# Linking to a second tabItem inside a Tab.Panel view

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to link to a tab.Panel view and have the second or third (not the first) tabItem be selected?

Currently i have a view that's linking to a tab.Panel that looks like this:

```
Ext.define("app.view.MyView", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'myview',
    alias: 'widget.myview',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'dev.view.1',
        'dev.view.2',
        'dev.view.3',
        'dev.view.4',
        'dev.view.5',
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        title: 'My Title',
        ui: 'neutral',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-2'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-3'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-4'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-5'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

As of now when i load in the view, 'xtype-of-view-1' is set as the active tab.
But is it possible to load in the tab.Panel view but having one of the other tabs active and pressed?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.define("app.view.MyView", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'myview',
    alias: 'widget.myview',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'dev.view.1',
        'dev.view.2',
        'dev.view.3',
        'dev.view.4',
        'dev.view.5',
    ],

    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        title: 'My Title',
        ui: 'neutral',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-2'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-3'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-4'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'xtype-of-view-5'
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
         var items = this.getItems(),
             itemIdx,
             Ext.each(items, function(item, idx) {
                 if (item.xtype == 'xtype-of-view-2') {
                     itemIdx = idx;
                     return false;
                 }
             });
             this.setActiveItem(itemIdx);
    }
});
```

you could also watch the awesome video guide http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/tabs-toolbars

You have to add a controller to you app. in controller add a reference

```
refs: {
    myview: 'myview',
    list: 'anotherview list'
},
control : {
    list: {
        itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
    }
},
onListItemTap: function (ct) {
    var myview = this.getMyview();
    myview.setActiveItem(1)
}
```

Please get read the sencha tutorial if you have no clue about MVC in sencha touch. Eg. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find'

Comment: the code was not tested really, sorry... :) in your case items is an Array.

Comment: initialize: function() {
          var items = this.getItems(),
              itemIdx = 1
              this.setActiveItem(itemIdx);
     }
This code works, but only if it's in the same view.. I need to but this code into a tap function in another view... Any ideas how that function might look?

Answer (score 0):

you cand add bello config in to `tab.panel`

```
activeItem :2
```

for active third item insted of first